# R - how to eliminate upper x% of a vector

Tags: r, percentage, outliers

I need to throw out the outliers of my variable.
I want to reduce the upper 10 percent of my variable.
Yet I have no clue how to find out which are my upper 10 %.
If I make a random cut at 30 I get the upper 3.45 %.

```
dat$T102_01[dat$T102_01 < 30]
```

Is there any way to tell r not to take the values < 30 but the first 90% of the values?

Since I don´t want to make a content based decision (anything above 30 is unrealistic) it would be better to take the upper 10% of all variables I have assesed.

I would be very thankful for any comments

Sorry I can´t add a picture of my plot. The distribution is skewed and most values are between 0-30, very view values are between 30-100

Comment: You could use `?quantile` to get the %cutpoint and then just subset your vector. eg `x = 20:1 ; cutpoint = quantile(x, p=0.9) ; x[x < cutpoint]`

Answer (score 2):

I would use the quantile function as follows:

```
x <- rnorm(50)
p90 <- quantile(x = x,probs = .9)
want <- x[x<p90]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by doing a `sort` and find the value 90% of the way through it:

```
vec <- rnorm(1000)

cut <- sort( vec )[ round( length( vec ) * 0.9 ) ]

vec <- vec[ vec < cut ]
```

So we sort the vector, and take the value at the point 90% of the way through the vector as a `cut` point. We then use the `cut` point to take only the bottom 90% of the main vector.